# VB There is no row at position 0

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I have a database that currently has nothing in it and I'm trying to create and save the first record, but end up getting an error that says "There is no row at position 0."

What I've done is instead of having a textbox that allows a user to select a shipper or receiver name, I've pulled those out and put in comboboxes that I've bound to the appropriate field in two other databases (shippers.mdb and receivers.mdb).

So, on clicking the "save" button, I want to save the selecteditems (saved to strings) from those comboboxes to each column cell in the database that I want. However, the system isn't letting me save the record at all. I've been trying to figure out how to save the information for the "current" record being edited or entered so for some reason I've decided to use (0), thinking that might work but it seems that isn't right. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Button16_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button16.Click

        Me.OrdersDataSet.orders(0).orderstatus = ComboBox13.SelectedItem.ToString()
        shipper1 = ComboBox8.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Me.OrdersDataSet.orders(0).SHIPPER1 = shipper1
        RECEIVER1 = ComboBox9.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Me.OrdersDataSet.orders(0).RECEIVER1 = RECEIVER1
        billtoacct = ComboBox7.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Me.OrdersDataSet.orders(0).BILLTOACCT = billtoacct
        driverassigned = ComboBox10.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Me.OrdersDataSet.orders(0).DRIVERASSIGNED = driverassigned
        truckassigned = ComboBox11.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Me.OrdersDataSet.orders(0).TRUCKASSIGNED = truckassigned
        trailerassigned = ComboBox12.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Me.OrdersDataSet.orders(0).TRAILERASSIGNED = trailerassigned

        Me.Validate()
        Me.OrdersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager12.UpdateAll(Me.OrdersDataSet)
    End Sub
```

What should I be using instead because I can't seem to find something to let me save (or substitute) the combo box items for the current record? I did check in the table adapter that the CRUD is there and I went through to make sure it's set up to fill, update, etc.

Thanks for having a look.

Comment: what is OrdersDataSet in this code?

Comment: Hi Kiran, that is the dataset that I want to save to.

Comment: but you don't have the rows in your dataset,so you cannot refere the dataset like that

Comment: Well, true...that's my dilemma. How do I refer to them in this case?

Comment: what these will do   Me.Validate()
        Me.OrdersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager12.UpdateAll(Me.OrdersDataSet)

Comment: @Kiran: I'm going to assume you don't know the answer.

Comment: @Shawn What Kiran is saying is there are no rows in your dataset. What you need to do is create a table, then add your columns and finally add your data to those columns... Also what database are you using?

Comment: Hi Mr CoDeXeR...yes, there are no rows because I am creating the first record. The table is there...it's the OrdersDataSet. All the information about my table is there in my code, table adapter and all. It's an access mdb. I'm just not sure how to reference the column prior to saving the first row. I dragged the fields from the database on to my form and know the table is there, it's just empty. I just want to be able to put the Combobox selecteditems into their respective columns so that information gets saved with the other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot.... PUT ALL OF THIS IN YOUR BUTTON CLICK EVENT AND CHANGE AS NEEDED...

```
Dim customerOrders As DataSet = New DataSet("CustomerOrders")
Dim ordersTable As DataTable = customerOrders.Tables.Add("Orders")

'ADD YOUR COLUMNS YOU NEED TO...'
ordersTable.Columns.Add("OrderQuantity", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
ordersTable.Columns.Add("CompanyName", Type.GetType("System.String"))

'AND WHATEVER ELSE YOU NEED TO ADD, CHANGE AS NEEDED'

    ' Add YOUR ROWS to those columns for the datatable.
ordersTable .Rows.Add(25, "Indocin")
ordersTable .Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel")
ordersTable .Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine")
ordersTable .Rows.Add(21, "Combivent")
ordersTable .Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin")
```

Then you have your dataset with the table and your data to set to your table adapter manager

Thanks!